# Constructing a structure in matlab

Tags: matlab, structure

Could someone please help me in constructing this structure?
[image]

As one can see, I have to import this file from excel and convert it into a structure as shown. I have been able to develop a code which can create structures by manually entering Id numbers. For instance if I enter 150 it gives a structure for 150 as shown.

However I have to automate the process, i.e. I want matlab to identify the unique Ids and create the entire structure with all its data and timing in each of its ID.

Here's my code

```
function [ DynData ] = myfunction( filename )



[dat1, dat2, dat3] = xlsread(filename);
flds = dat3(1,:);
InputData = cell2struct(dat3(2:end,:),flds,2);


uIDs = unique( cell2mat(dat3(2:end, 2))) ;


        for j = 1:length(dat3)
            uIDs = dat3(j);

            i=1;
            for k = 2:length(dat3(:,1))
                if dat3{k,2} == {uIDs}


                IDnumber = ['ID',num2str(uIDs)];
                DynData.(IDnumber).time(1,i) = dat3{k,1};
                DynData.(IDnumber).ID(1,i) = dat3{k,2};
                DynData.(IDnumber).data(1,i) = dat3(k,3);

                i=i+1;



                end
            end
        end


end
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: first improvement, you can avoid to store an unneeded variable with the symbol `~`.  `[~,~,dat] = xlsread('filename');`

Comment: Very easy to do. First take the unique IDs as you already do, then use arrayfun (to iterate over the unique IDs) and then to select the corresponding rows where the second column is exactly the iterated ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to load my .xlsx into tables for easier access.

Try this function:

### UPDATE

if id is a number, you cannot use it directly as a field name in your structure. The first character in a field name must be a letter. You can fix this by using a prefix:

```
function dynData=tableImport(file)
% Imports data from .xls file with columns 'Time' 'Id' 'Data' into
% structure dynData with fieldnames=unique(id) each of which is in turn a
% struct array with fields Time and Data.

% Get data
tab=readtable(file);
% Group by id
G=findgroups(tab.Id);

% Extract id and structure
[id, st]=splitapply(@groupTable,tab,G);

% Build dynData
fieldNames=strsplit(sprintf('id%i\n',id));
for i=1:length(id)
    dynData.(fieldNames{i})=st{i};
end
end

function [ID, struc]=groupTable(time,id,data)
% Function for finding id-name and splitting  time and data into a struct.
ID=id(1);
struc={struct('Time',num2cell(time),'Data',data)}; % stored in cell
end
```

Although if I were you I'd rather store my data in a structure array with fieldnames

- id (string)
- time (array)
- data (array/cellarray)

for easier access in for-loops

### UPDATE 2

This is what I tried to suggest as a better structure:

```
function dynData=tableImport2(file)
% Imports data from .xls file with columns 'Time' 'Id' 'Data' into
% structure dynData with fieldnames=unique(id) each of which is in turn a
% struct array with fields Time and Data.

% Get data
tab=readtable(file);

% Group by id
G=findgroups(tab.Id);

% Extract id and structure
dynData=splitapply(@(time,id,data)struct('Id',id(1),'Time',time,'Data',{data}),tab,G);
end
```

Comment: Thank you for an elaborate answer, However, I tried using your code but there's an error on line; tab = readtable(file); whenever I try to call the function tableImport('test') - where test.xlsx is the excel file it gives the following error: using readtable (line 129)
Unable to open file 'test'.

Error in tableImport (line 7)
tab=readtable(file);

Comment: Are you sure you've given the full file path or that the file is on your path/current folder? Sounds like you might perhaps have the file open somewhere else? Maybe in `fopen`? Alternatively saved without the correct permissions.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to make it work but now it gives the following error:    Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Error in tableImport (line 16)
    dynData.(id{i})=st{i};

Comment: Therefore, I tried replacing {} brackets with () brackets but still does not work. Help please

Comment: Does your table look like in the image or are the columns different? Is id a number or a string? If it is a number it won't work as MATLAB doesn't allow field names which don't start with a letter.

Comment: It is exactly as I have shown it in the image. "Id" is the name of the column and it consists of various numbers.

Comment: Ok, In that case, as I mentioned it is impossible to create such a structure since the field name strings cannot start with a number. You need to either accept a prefix before the id or use a different structure.

Comment: Updated my question to reflect a suggested solution

Comment: But, that was a big help. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Otherwise see my second suggestion for what I believe to be a better way of storing data in structs

Comment: Amazing man!! You made it very simple for me. Second solution is good but, the first one was much useful for me. However, if I add one more numbers column in my excel file and I want values in that column to reflect in the structure 1. How can I do it?

Comment: in the local function `groupTable` add the table columns (order matters) and then change the call to `struct` to match what you are looking for. For numeric data: `struc={struct('Time',num2cell(time),'Data',data, 'NewFieldName', num2cell(NewNumericDataColumn))};`

Comment: That was Awesome!! I am really impressed with your skills. Can You please tell me if you have your own blog or online course? I would really like to take lessons to develop my Matlab skills!

Comment: No, sorry I'm self-taught and very curious, that's all :) I've learned mostly by reading documentation/original code/fooling around.

Comment: If this has solved your issue, would you mind marking your question as answered for future reference?